# JFlip jQuery plugin - not loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a book style page turn effect on some images so I decided to use the JQuery plugin, JFlip. The plugin seems to be doing what it is supposed to do except display the image. I have checked the Network tab and the images are being loaded. Also, I can see the Canvas element JFlip has created but it is just a blank space.

I have some code:

```
<ul id="g1">
    <li>
      <img src="img/proforma.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/proforma2.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And some javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jFlip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#g1").jFlip(700,230,{background:"green",cornersTop:false});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work, just the plugins are a bit old. See my code below :

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/excanvasX.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <script src="http://www.jquery.info/scripts/jFlip/jquery.jflip-0.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="g1">
    <li>
      <img src="http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif">
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

`$("#g1").jFlip(700,230,{background:"green",cornersTop:false});`

See the full solution here : http://jsbin.com/iqaran/1/edit . Remember to `run with js` in jsbin

Cheers !

Comment: I have an image problem in another question you should check out too.

Comment: Post the link here.I will see what i can do .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218805/background-image-shows-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-not-ie9

Comment: @SteveW. I have posted my answer to the question in stack.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that script is so old (2008), you need to include the jQuery migrate script.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFw4p/)</kbd>

**Scripts**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jFlip.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="g1">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also make sure to wrap your executing code in a [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) so the images get the change to render.

**JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#g1").jFlip(700,230,{background:"green",cornersTop:false});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it already doesn't seem to work. The images are still hidden and do not display on the page so I am assuming the plug-in is doing its job just not rendering the images.

Comment: Updated answer, you'll also want to wrap your plugin execution on a DOM ready wrapper. If that doesn't work, it _has_ to be an issue with your images since both answers have it working.